# Deduplication with FuzzyWuzzy creating new columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, fuzzywuzzy

I've been trying to find duplicates for all cells in a column called "text" that at least match 90% and only keep the first row in case of duplicates found (and remove the rest of the duplicate rows). This should then be displayed in a new csv file.

I have tried to do so with this MWE, however it seems to create 2 new columns called "Matches" and "Combined" that I don't need, as a new csv without the duplicates and with only the first occurence would be the eventual goal.

```
import pandas as pd
from dedupe_FuzzyWuzzy import deduplication

df = pd.read_csv('/path/input.csv')
# normal duplication drop
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='text', keep='first')

# threshold drop
df_final = deduplication.deduplication(df, ['text'],threshold=90)

# send output to csv
df_final.to_csv('/path/deduplicated.csv',index=False)
```

Comment: `dedupe_FuxxyWuzzy` does not drop duplicates. If you look at the source code you will see it It applies Fuzzy matching to DF column contents and creates those 2 new columns which you can use in whatever way, if useful. You could maybe use the Matches column values to form groups for duplicate deletion but it does not look straightforward. See my code answer below.

Comment: thank you @user19077881 I was just wondering how to do it with a csv and cross checking its cell contents.

Comment: I'm not sure whst you mean. Reading CSV into DF, checking/changing, writing out result as CSV is sinolest. I suppose it would be possible to read  a CSV line by line, split each line by the separator, put all the column values into a List and then use my checking code. But its the same process really so I don't see what it achieves. Pls explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code, with a basic example, uses `rapidfuzz` to mark fuzzy-matched duplications in a text column of a pandas DataFrame. Note: higher threshold means more severe matching. The code goes through a List of text values from the column, checks for fuzzy-duplication and marks for deletion. A deletion list is then used as a mask to remove selected DataFrame rows.

```
import pandas as pd
import rapidfuzz
txt = ['abc', 'abcdx', 'xyx', 'abcdef', 'xyxg','abcde', 'abxdx', 'xyxk', 'abcdex', '1234', 'abxdx2', '12345']
vals = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': txt, 'col2': vals})


def mark_dupes(txt_col, threshold = 90):

    txt_list = txt_col.to_list()
    marked = [True]*len(txt_list)
    
    for i, txt in enumerate(txt_list):
        if not marked[i]:      #don't check duplicates of text rows marked for removal
            continue
        for j, others in enumerate(txt_list[i+1::]): 
            if marked[i+j+1]:     # only look through vals not already marked for removal
                if rapidfuzz.fuzz.ratio(txt, others, score_cutoff = threshold):
                    marked[i+j+1] = False   # mark for removal
    return marked

chk = mark_dupes(df['col1'], threshold = 80)

dfx = df[chk]
print(dfx)
```

which prints

```
     col1  col2
0     abc     1
2     xyx     3
3  abcdef     4
6   abxdx     7
9    1234    10
```